# L-BFGS-B converging in iteration 0 in R

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to fit an F distribution to a given set using `optim`'s L-BFGS-B method. For some reason, it is always converging at iteration 0, which obviously doesn't approximate the parameters I am looking for.

For reproduction purposes,

```
# A sample x ~ F(5, 8) with 5,000 observations.
x <- rf(50000, 5, 8)

# Sample density.
f <- density(x, from=min(x), to=max(x))

# Error function (root mean squared error) to be minimized.
# Noteworthy F's degrees of freedom are rounded since they
# are required to be integers.
rmse <- function(params) {
  sqrt(sum((df(f$x, round(params[1]), round(params[2])) - f$y)^2))
}

# L-BFGS-B optimization.
o <- optim(c(50, 50),              # Initial parameters.
           rmse,
           lower=c(0, 0),          # F's degrees of freedom's domain
           upper=c(2^16, 2^16),    # is [0,Inf).
           method='L-BFGS-B',
           control=list(trace=3))

print(o)
```

Here we should expect `o$par` $\approx (5, 8)$ to correspond with our `x` definition. Instead, the optimization does not take place and returns the initial parameters, $(50, 50)$, claiming

```
 $message
 [1] "CONVERGENCE: NORM OF PROJECTED GRADIENT <= PGTOL"
```

Any hint towards a successful optimization?

Comment: Function round may not be differentiable, can you exclude round and then rerun the code? Also what is df? Can you explicitly state that function?

Comment: continuing on my previous comment, once you get the floating point values, just use `round` function to get the nearest integer. You will never find an optimization routine that gives you integer values unless you take the route of genetic algorithm/differential evolution, even then the values will be with floating point and you have to round it to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the `round()` function as it allows infinite optimal solutions. That is, $(5.1,8.1)$ is optimal and so is $(4.9,7.9)$. Getting rid of the `round()` function works.

```
    # A sample x ~ F(5, 8) with 5,000 observations.
x <- rf(50000, 5, 8)

# Sample density.
f <- density(x, from=min(x), to=max(x))

# Error function (root mean squared error) to be minimized.
# Noteworthy F's degrees of freedom are rounded since they
# are required to be integers.
rmse <- function(params) {
  sqrt(sum((df(f$x, params[1], params[2]) - f$y)^2))
}

# L-BFGS-B optimization.
o <- optim(c(50, 50),              # Initial parameters.
           rmse,
           lower=c(0, 0),          # F's degrees of freedom's domain
           upper=c(2^16, 2^16),    # is [0,Inf).
           method='L-BFGS-B',
           control=list(trace=3))

print(o)
```

Comment: That is the point, F bears integer parameters only.

Comment: Once you get the values/parameters with decimal points from L BFGS, then you can use round function to make the parameters an integer. I do this all the time in engineering optimization and works perfectly.

Comment: That's a nice approach however some functions used had integer domain. I solved using `GenSA` package for simulated annealing; results are poor however.